# about affiliate tracking code under wordpress and woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, affiliate

I'm trying to join affiliate program and my affiliate service provider give me the following code to make sure they can tracking every order number, and there are some information I have to fill, but I don't know how to make it work, I will be very grateful  if anyone can help.

I'm using wordpress and woocommerce for my website.

Code I Have to Fill：

```
order: 'FILL ORDER NUMBER', // order number
```

Whole Code For Body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    var VARemoteLoadOptions = {
      whiteLabel: { id: 8, siteId: ####, domain: 'vbtrax.com' },
      conversion: true,
      conversionData: {
        step: 'sale', // conversion name
        revenue: '12', // revenue share
        order: 'FILL ORDER NUMBER', // order number
      },
      locale: "en-US",
      mkt: true
    };

    (function (c, o, n, v, e, r, l, y) {
      c['VARemoteLoadOptions'] = e;
      r = o.createElement(n), l = o.getElementsByTagName(n)[0];
      r.async = 1;
      r.src = v;
      l.parentNode.insertBefore(r, l);
    })(
      window,
      document,
      'script',
      'https://cdn.vbtrax.com/javascripts/va.js',
      VARemoteLoadOptions
    );
  })();

</script>
```

And the Code For Header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
var VARemoteLoadOptions = {
whiteLabel: { id: 8, siteId: ####, domain: 'vbtrax.com' },
locale: "en-US", mkt: true
};
(function (c, o, n, v, e, r, l, y) {
c['VARemoteLoadOptions'] = e; r = o.createElement(n), l = o.getElementsByTagName(n)[0];
r.async = 1; r.src = v; l.parentNode.insertBefore(r, l);
})(window, document, 'script', 'https://cdn.vbtrax.com/javascripts/va.js', VARemoteLoadOptions);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Certainly your affiliate service provider provided *some* instructions and/or direction? Have you reached out to them? Please try to include more relevant details.

Comment: All they gave me are two codes and told me copy the following code to <header>and<body>
I'm already edit it to my question,hope it could help.
thank you anyway.